# alter system kill session still can't release, wait or?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

a table in oracle database is locked when a network issue occur （Nightmare begin）.
then i run the command `alter system kill session (sid,serial#)` .--target killed, but the table still not release.
then i google solution, find 2 ways : 1. restart database. 2. `kill -9`  via OS.

but i have no rights to shutdown the database and unfortunately can't log in the SERVER OS.
so is there any others way to release the table, or i only can wait for the resource killed after a long time?

Comment: What was the killed session doing?  If it was doing a large DML, there's really nothing you can do other than wait for all the changes to be rolled back.  You *could* kill the process, but that would probably corrupt your data and require recovery.

Comment: This question would likely get better responses if asked on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for sharing the website ,and after the large data rolled back, the table finally released

Answer (score 0):

Ask your dba to help. Strange to see you have alter system privileges and can not stop the database. Your session is most likely rolling back a big transaction. That can take a lot of time. This can be done a bit quicker when the instance takes over this recovery. The instance will do this if your session is no longer able to do that, because your sessions background process no longer exists.

For this reason, killing your background session from the OS might speeds things up.